How to create universal model to deserialize response from external API
I'm creating an endpoint to get prices from crypto markets for specific cryptocurrency.
I'm using API of Kucoin and Binance. When I get a response, in both responses there are bids and asks fields. Both of API responses have different structure, bud I need only this fields. How can I create an universal model and deserialize responses from api into this model?
My current code:
// OrderBookResponse
public class OrderBookResponse
{
    public OrderBookData Data { get; set; }
}

// OrderBookData
public class OrderBookData
{
    public List<List<string>> Bids { get; set; }
    public List<List<string>> Asks { get; set; }
}

KucoinService
    public ExchangeRate GetExchangeRateAsync(GetRatesModel getRates)
    {
        var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(CryptoExchangeUrls.KucoinApi)
        {
            Path = "/api/v1/market/orderbook/level2_20",
            Query = $"symbol={getRates.BaseCurrency.ToUpper()}-{getRates.QuoteCurrency.ToUpper()}"
        };

        using var client = new HttpClient();

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(uriBuilder.Uri).Result;

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            throw new Exception($"HTTP request failed with status code {response.StatusCode}");
        }

        OrderBookResponse deserializedResponse = response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<OrderBookResponse>().Result;

        ExchangeRate exchangeRate = new ExchangeRate()
        {
            ExchangeName = "Kucoin",
            Rate = PriceHelper.GetAveragePrice(deserializedResponse.Data)
        };

        return exchangeRate;
    }

Binance Service
    public ExchangeRate GetExchangeRateAsync(GetRatesModel getRates)
    {
        var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder($"{CryptoExchangeUrls.BinanceApi}/api/v3/depth")
        {
            Query = $"limit=10&symbol={getRates.BaseCurrency.ToUpper()}{getRates.QuoteCurrency.ToUpper()}"
        };

        using var client = new HttpClient();

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(uriBuilder.Uri).Result;

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            throw new Exception($"HTTP request failed with status code {response.StatusCode}");
        }

        OrderBookResponse deserializedResponse = response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<OrderBookResponse>().Result;

        ExchangeRate exchangeRate = new ExchangeRate()
        {
            ExchangeName = "Binance",
            Rate = PriceHelper.GetAveragePrice(deserializedResponse.Data)
        };

        return exchangeRate;
    }

I'm using this endpoints:
https://api.kucoin.com/api/v1/market/orderbook/level2_20?symbol=BTC-USDT
https://api.binance.com/api/v3/depth?limit=10&symbol=BTCUSDT

You could use a template function that can try to deserialze your response string into an object. With a model like this:
public class GenericApiResponse
{
    public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}

You can use a very general function like
public async Task<GenericApiResponse> ExecuteRequest(MethodEnum method, string resource, AuthModel authType,
        object body = null, Dictionary<string, string> queryParams = null, Dictionary<string, string> headers = null)
    {
        Method requestMethod = MethodEnumExtensions.ToHttpMethod(method);
        var request = new RestRequest(resource, requestMethod);
        
        if (authType.Authenticate)
        {
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"{authType.TokenType} {_authToken}");
        }
        
        if (body != null)
        {
            request.AddJsonBody(body);
        }

        if (queryParams != null)
        {
            foreach (var param in queryParams)
            {
                request.AddQueryParameter(param.Key, param.Value);
            }
        }

        if (headers != null)
        {
            foreach (var header in headers)
            {
                request.AddHeader(header.Key, header.Value);
            }
        }

        var response = await _client.ExecuteAsync(request);

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Received error status code for request {resource}, code: {response.StatusCode}, message: {response.Content ?? "NO MESSAGE"}");
        }

        return new GenericApiResponse
        {
            Content = response.Content,
            StatusCode = response.StatusCode
        };
    }

And then to make the function work with any object
public async Task<TResponse> ExecuteRequest<TResponse>(MethodEnum method, string resource, AuthModel authType,
        object body = null, Dictionary<string, string> queryParams = null, Dictionary<string, string> headers = null)
    {
        var response = await ExecuteRequest(method, resource, authType, body, queryParams, headers);

        if (response == null || response.Content == null)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Received null response");

            return default(TResponse);
        }

        TResponse result;
        try
        {
            result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResponse>(response.Content);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResponse>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response.Content));
        }

        return result;
    }

